# OutOfMemory error in a queue consumer application

Tags: amazon-s3, memory-management, jvm, out-of-memory, amazon-sqs

I have a datapipeline component that reads SQS messages, generated at S3 upload trigger, and parses and publishes the message for a batchpipeline component. 
I have recently observed that in production system, my datapipeline keeps crashing with OutOfMemory error under heavy load but it never crashes when tested locally with similar loads? The batchpipeline never seems to crash in Production ever.

How do I go about debugging it when I can't reproduce it locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have found a solution, after 2 weeks, to my problem above, I figured I'll document it for others and my future self.

I wasn't able to replicate the issue because the aws command-

aws s3 cp --recursive dir s3://input-queue/dir

somehow wasn't uploading messages fast enough that it could stress my local datapipeline. So I brought down the datapipeline and once there were 10k SQS messages in the queue, I started it and as expected, it crashed with Out Of Memory error after processing ~3000 messages. It turns out that the pipeline was able to handle continuous throughput but it broke when it started with 10k message load.

My hypothesis was that the issue is happening because Java garbage collection is unable to properly clean up objects after execution. So, I started analyzing the generated heap dump and after some days of research, I stumbled on the possible root cause for Out of Memory error. There were ~5000 instances of my MessageHandlerTask class, when ideally they should have been GC'd after being processed and not keep on piling up.

Further investigation on that line of thought led me to the root cause- it turned out that the code was using Executors.newFixedThreadPool() to create an ExecutorService for submitting tasks to. This implementation used an unbounded queue of tasks, so if too many tasks were submitted, all of them waited in the queue, taking up huge memory.
The reality was similar- messages were being polled faster than they could be processed. This caused a lot of valid MessageHandlerTask instances to be created that filled the heap memory if there was a message backlog.

The fix was to have create a ThreadPoolExecutor with an ArrayBlockingQueue of capacity 100 so that there is a cap on number of instances of MessageHandlerTask and its member variables.

Having figured out the fix, I moved on to optimize the pipeline for maximum throughput by varying the maximumPoolSize of the ThreadPoolExecutor. It turned out there were some SQS connection exceptions happening at higher thread counts. Further investigation revealed that increasing the SQS connection pool size ameliorated this issue.
I ultimately settled on a count of 40 threads for the given Xmx heap size of 1.5G and 80 SQS connection pool size so that the task threads do not run out of SQS connections while processing. This helped me achieve a throughput of 44 messages/s with just a single instance of datapipeline.

I also found out why the batchpipeline never crashed in Production, despite suffering from a similar ExecutorService implementation- turns out the datapipeline could be stressed by too many concurrent S3 uploads but the messages for batchpipeline were produced by datapipeline in a gradual fashion. Besides, the batchpipeline had a much higher throughput that I benchmarked at 347 messages/s when using 70 maximumPoolSize.